# libGDX autoresizing image button

Tags: resize, libgdx, imagebutton, scaling, tablelayout

i want a list with image buttons to be displayed in my libGDX app.
The idea is that the image has a size of lets say 400x100 pixels.
I need the list to be able to display the images stretched to width of the screen - the height of the image should be resized to keep the aspect ratio.

But everytime i try to do this the image won't get resized properly.
The image is not stretched when smaller then screen width or the padding get's bad or the aspect ration gets wrong.

Could you suggest a way to do this, i'm struggling to find any solution..
The actor must be Button a button.. (need "checked"/selected functionality)

I tried to do something like this:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);

Texture t1 = ... snip ...
Texture t2 = ... snip ...
ImageButton i1 = new ImageButton( new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(t1));
ImageButton i2 = new ImageButton( new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(t2));

i1.getImageCell().expandX().fillX();
i2.getImageCell().expandX().fillX();

table.add(i1).expandX().fillX();
table.row();
table.add(i2).expandX().fillX();

getStage().add(table);
```

Comment: Are you using a `camera` or if you are using the latest nightlies are you using `Viewport`? I think there are the things you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
imageButton.setBounds(x, y, 128, 128);
imageButton.getImageCell().expand().fill();
```

Comment: Actually it's suggested by the Libgdx official guide not to set the bounds of the widget but rather to use the .width() and .height() methods of the cell that will contain the widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
float screenWidth = this.stage.getWidth();
i2.setWidth(screenWidth);
```

If i understand correctly, this should do what you want.

Comment: Hello, thanx for answer. but the code is ignoring setWidth compleetly. The expandX() and fillX() together with table.setFillParent() do the job when width is smaller than width of screen.. The problem is having the images scale and fill the height of their respective cells. Sometimes the images overlap horizontally and sometimes there is 30pix padding between them, when i do the Table.drawdebug(stage); ... there is no padding between the cells, but there is empty space abowe/below the image as such. DUNO why.. :(